# In JS, is there a way to assign values to multiple fields of an object without writing the name of the object each time?

Tags: javascript

For example, something like this:

```
btn.{
 innerText = "hello",
 style.{
  fontSize = "24px",
  outline = "none"
 }
}
```

Instead of:

```
btn.innerText = "hello";
btn.style.fontSize = "24px";
btn.style.outline = "none";
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Yes, there is, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Comment: What @Teemu said.

I'd suggest going through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Introduction

It will take you a week, but teach you all the basics of JavaScript. It is a concise and well written guide.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do the following when you assign the object to a variable:

```
const obj = {
 name: 'user54321',
 age: 30,
 ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a literal object initializer:

```
let a = 1, b=2, c=3

const newObj = {a,b,c};
console.log(newObj.a);
// expected output: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

[Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) does exactly what you need:

```js
// declare obj with some props
const btn = {
  innerText: "initial"
};

// see what we have
console.log(JSON.stringify(btn))

// assign (and re-assign) some props
Object.assign(btn, {
  innerText: "hello",
  style: {
    fontSize: "24px",
    outline: "none"
  }
})

// see what changed
console.log(JSON.stringify(btn))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const btn = {
  innerText: "hello",
  style: {
    fontSize: "24px",
    outline: "none"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. For future readers it's far more interesting to see explained *why* this answers the question. And answers with explanation tend to have better acceptance.

Comment: @GertArnold that is exactly what most of the answers above did, and not to mention that they're also off topic. I don't see voting them down. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not my downvote. I saw your answer in the review queue. Decided not to vote for deletion but to leave a general advice that would improve your answer. Feel free to indicate where your answer is better than the others. That's OK when done in fairness.

Comment: There's a wide-spread misconception among higher-rep users (the ones having review privileges) that code-only answers should be flagged "not an answer", which makes them liable for deletion. Something to keep in mind.